# How to properly map a tuple function across a Seq[A]?

Tags: scala, dictionary, tuples, sequence

I have a function that is attempting to build a JSON object containing a representation of multiple tuples that are stored in a `Seq[A]`, where `A` is a `(Loop, Option[User])`.  My code looks like so:

```
def loops = Action {
    val page : Int = 1
    val orderBy : Int = 1
    val filter : String = ""
    val jsonifyLoops : (Loop, Option[User]) => Map[String, String] = { 
      case (loop,user) =>
            Map(
                "name" -> loop.name,
                "created_at" -> loop.createdAt.map(dateFormat.format).getOrElse(""),
                "deleted_at" -> loop.deletedAt.map(dateFormat.format).getOrElse(""),
                "user_name" -> user.map(_.name).getOrElse("")
            )
    }
    Ok(toJson(Map(
        "loops" -> toJson(
            Loop.list( page = page, orderBy = orderBy, filter = ("%"+filter+"%") )
                .items.map( jsonifyLoops )
            )
        )
    ))
}
```

`Loops.list` produces a `Page[A]`, from the helper class below:

```
case class Page[A](items: Seq[A], page: Int, offset: Long, total: Long) {
    lazy val prev = Option(page - 1).filter(_ >= 0)
    lazy val next = Option(page + 1).filter(_ => (offset + items.size) < total)
}
```

Thus, `Loops.list(...).items` should get me a `Seq[(Loop, Option[User])]`, onto which I should be able to apply a map function.  I've defined my `jsonifyLoops` function to have what I think is the appropriate prototype, but I must be doing something wrong, because the compiler throws me the following error:

```
    [error] [...] Application.scala:42: type mismatch;
    [error]  found   : (models.Loop, Option[models.User]) => Map[String,String]
    [error]  required: (models.Loop, Option[models.User]) => ?
    [error]                     .items.map( jsonifyLoops )
    [error]                                 ^
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your function `jsonifyLoops` takes two arguments: a `Loop` and an `Option[User]`. However, the members of `items` are tuples of the type `(Loop, Option[User])`, and thus `items.map` requires as an argument a function of one argument accepting that tuple. So, you need to convert `jsonifyLoops` from a binary function to a unary function that takes a pair of arguments; `Function2#tupled` will do this for you:

```
scala> :t jsonifyLoops
(Loop, Option[User]) => Map[String,String]
scala> :t jsonifyLoops.tupled
((Loop, Option[User])) => Map[String,String]
```

You'd use it like this:

```
Loop.list(page = page, orderBy = orderBy, filter = ("%"+filter+"%"))
    .items.map(jsonifyLoops.tupled)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a default case to your pattern matching within jasonifyLoops.
In absence of a default case, if your case statement fails you return a Unit. 
So something like this should work:

```
val jsonifyLoops : (Loop, Option[User]) => Map[String, String] = { 
  case (loop,user) =>
        Map(
            "name" -> loop.name,
            "created_at" -> loop.createdAt.map(dateFormat.format).getOrElse(""),
            "deleted_at" -> loop.deletedAt.map(dateFormat.format).getOrElse(""),
            "user_name" -> user.map(_.name).getOrElse("")
        )
  case _ => Map[String, String]()
}
```

This just says that if the input does not match, return an empty Map. However, you should replace this with whatever handling you want to do for the default case.

Comment: Note that the default case could be written as `case _ => Map.empty`

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not seem to solve the problem.  I get the same error from the compiler.  Any other ideas?

Comment: Can you also add the definition of toJson to your question. I guess that should be causing the trouble.

Comment: toJson is defined in Play's Json library: http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.0/ScalaJson